# Weird Condition behaviour within ComponentDidUpdate

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I came up a weird situation while playing with javascript and react.

```
async componentDidUpdate(previousProps, previousState) {
    console.log(previousState.questionNo,this.state.questionNo);
    console.log(!previousState.questionNo === this.state.questionNo)
    if (!previousState.questionNo === this.state.questionNo) {
            console.log("I'm here")
            const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12); //12 is hardcoded i need to find sth better later
            const resp = await questionsApi.get(`/questions/${index}`);
            this.setState({ question: resp.data });
        }
    }
```

And when i check in console eventhough values are not equal component did not rendered. And also in console `console.log(!previousState.questionNo === this.state.questionNo)` awkwardly always provides false.

console output is like below:

```
1 1 Component.js:16
false Component.js:17
1 2 Component.js:16
false component.js:17
```

any idea what is going on ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
if (!previousState.questionNo === this.state.questionNo)
```

by

```
if (previousState.questionNo !== this.state.questionNo)
```

This is because doing `!previousState.questionNo` will convert the value to a boolean (mostly `false`) which will never be equal to `this.state.questionNo` as that is a number like `1`, `2`, etc

Comment: @WhisperTeam No problem, could you accept the answer if it helped you. Thanks :)